# How to remove file paths with a specific file extension from an array of paths?

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-2.0, filepath

I have an array that contains multiple file paths, with multiple file extensions:

```powershell
$Array = @("C:\aaa\aaa\abc.txt", "C:\aaa\aaa\bbb.txt", "C:\aaa\aaa\abc.c", "C:\aaa\aaa\abc.h", ...etc)
```

Now, I wanted to remove all file paths that have a `.txt` extension and did the following:

```powershell
$Array | Foreach {$_ | Where {$_ -notlike "*.txt"}}
```

It does remove the `.txt` file paths.

Since I'm still new to Powershell, I would like to know if this is the right way to do it or if there is a better solution (e.g. that doesn't use the `Foreach` statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not actually need a `Foreach-Object` here.  Just pipe the array to the `Where-Object` directly:

```powershell
PS > $Array = @("C:\aaa\aaa\abc.txt", "C:\aaa\aaa\bbb.txt", "C:\aaa\aaa\abc.c", "C:\aaa\aaa\abc.h")
PS > $Array | Where {$_ -notlike "*.txt"}
C:\aaa\aaa\abc.c
C:\aaa\aaa\abc.h
PS >
```

Of course, in this case, you could just use `-notlike` on the array itself:

```powershell
PS > $Array -notlike "*.txt"
C:\aaa\aaa\abc.c
C:\aaa\aaa\abc.h
PS >
```

This is because all of PowerShell's comparison operators work with both scalars as well as collections.  From the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx):

> When the input to an operator is a scalar value, comparison operators
>       return a Boolean value. When the input is a collection of values, the 
>       comparison operators return any matching values. If there are no matches
>       in a collection, comparison operators do not return anything.

Comment: That's quite useful to know! Thanks for your answer.